# Error binding CustomControl to Items of a ObservableCollection inside the Datatemplate of a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I have a DataGrid that have as Source an ObservableCollection of Site. I have some columns that are defined in a DataTemplate binding to properties of Site. The binding works perfectly when using builtin controls like TextBlock but I am not able to do it with a custom control. I have seen that this error appears in the console but I do not understand exactly what I have to do:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Port' property not found on 'object' ''TestControl' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=Port; DataItem='TestControl' (Name=''); target element is 'TestControl' (Name=''); target property is 'CameraName' (type 'String')

Here I attach snippets of the code I use;

DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid Name="SitesList" CanUserReorderColumns="True"  
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModel.Sites}"
                  PreparingCellForEdit="DataGrid_PreparingCellForEdit" 
                  >                      
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CameraTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <hv:TestControl CameraName="{Binding Path=Port}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="PortTemplate">
        <TextBox x:Name="PortTextBox"
            Text="{Binding Path=Port, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.Resources>
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Camera"
                            CellTemplate="{StaticResource CameraTemplate}"
                            MinWidth="100"/>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Port"
                            CellTemplate="{StaticResource PortTemplate}"
                            MinWidth="70"/>
</DataGrid.Columns></DataGrid>
```

ObservableCollection:

```
    private ObservableCollection<Site> m_sites = new ObservableCollection<Site>();
    public ObservableCollection<Site> Sites
    {
        get
        {
            return m_sites;
        }
        set
        {
            m_sites = value;
        }
    }
```

Site.cs:

```
namespace Wizard.View
{
    public class Site: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region properties
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null) {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }
        private string m_port = "0";
        public string Port
        {
            get
            {
                return m_port;
            }
            set
            {
                m_port = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Port");
            }
        }
        #endregion        
    }
}
```

TestControl.xaml.cs:

```
namespace Wizard.View.HelpersViews
{
    public partial class TestControl: UserControl
    {
        public TestControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string CameraName
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(CameraNameProperty); }
            set {
                Console.WriteLine(value);
                SetValue(CameraNameProperty, value);
                CameraNameTextBlock.Text = value;
            }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty CameraNameProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("CameraName",
                                        typeof(string),
                                        typeof(TestControl),
                                        new PropertyMetadata("0"));
    }
}
```

TestControl.xaml:

```
<UserControl
             x:Class="Wizard.View.HelpersViews.TestControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
             d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <CheckBox Margin ="5,0" Name="AddCameraCheck"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource ConfiguratorCheckBox}" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="CameraNameTextBlock" Width="175" Text="{Binding CameraName}" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

The column Port is bound correctly but Camera is not.

Comment: Looks like TestControl sets its DataContext to "this".

Comment: Sorry I have forgotten to add the TestControl code. I will add it now.

Comment: @KlausGütter So TestControl has itself as DataContext but should that change the fact that a Property can be bound or not? How would you do it instead?

Comment: Yes, this makes a difference. If no other Source is given in the Binding, WPF will try to resolve it in the DataContext. One possible solution would be to put the DataContext assignment one level deeper (i.e. on the StackPanel), then of course with ode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={TestControl}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TextBlock` in the `TestControl` should bind to the `CameraName` property of itself:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="CameraNameTextBlock" Width="175" Text="{Binding CameraName, 
                                       RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
```

...but you should remove this for the control to inherit the `DataContext` from the `DataGridRow`:

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

Also the CLR wrapper of a dependency property should only call `GetValue` and `SetValue`:

```
public string CameraName
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(CameraNameProperty); }
    set { SetValue(CameraNameProperty, value); }
}
```